# Sort hasMany relation in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have a simple relation 1:N to get some prices from a single model.

```
public function getPrices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Prices::className(), ['device_id' => 'id']);
    }
```

But I need prices objects sorteds by a specific property in this case `$value`

I've seen multiple examples in `Yii 1` but nothing in `Yii 2`

Thanks to @vishu i've tried this:

```
public function getPrices()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Prices::className(), ['device_id' => 'id'])
        ->viaTable(Prices::tableName(), ['device_id' => 'id'], function ($query) {

            $query->orderBy(['device_price' => SORT_DESC]);
        });

}
```

But now it returns a empty array.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think you can assign the  order by directly in relation

```
public function getPrices()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Prices::className(), ['device_id' => 'id'])->
      orderBy(['device_price' => SORT_DESC]);
}
```

Comment: Very useful to get another type of data since it returns an AR obj, such as user's last transaction : `orderBy('created_at DESC')->one();`

Answer (score 4):

Setting order directly in relation may not be reliable in particular cases. So you can set order in AR query

```
Device::find()
->where(['id' => $id])
->with('prices' => function(\yii\db\ActiveQuery $query) {
    $query->orderBy('device_price DESC');
})
->one();
```

Comment: inside the with() are Bracktes missing []

Answer (score 1):

Use like.......

```
public function getPrices()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Prices::className(), ['device_id' => 'id'])
                ->orderBy(['device_price' => SORT_DESC]);
 }
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690401/activerecord-where-and-order-on-via-table)

Comment: check your id and then run?

Comment: check this compare id `['device_id' => 'id']`

Comment: wich?, hasMany relation, viaTable? or I have to set it in andWhere clousure?

Comment: refer this link....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690401/activerecord-where-and-order-on-via-table

Comment: But in this link, he had a N:M relation, and i have 1:N