# Yii2 order items of many-to-many relation

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I've 2 tables (sliders, images) related with junction (sliders_images) table, the relation work fine but I nedd to get related data with specific order, the attribute that define the right order is in the junction table, the relation is defined as:

```
public function getImages(){
    return $this->hasMany(Images::className(), ['id' => 'image_id'])
        ->viaTable('sliders_images', ['slider_id' => 'id'], function($query){
            $query->orderBy('sliders_images.display_order ASC');
        });
}
```

when i call `$model->images` I receive the correct images but the wrong order, using foreach the images was ordered by id, how i can get the images ordered by other attribute?

Answer (score 3):

The right way is to add a join with junction table `->joinWith('slidersImages')` for get the junction table attributes and then order by one of those. The full code:

```
public function getImages(){
        return $this->hasMany(Images::className(), ['id' => 'image_id'])
        ->via('slidersImages')
        ->joinWith('slidersImages SI')
        ->orderBy('SI.display_order ASC');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case `orderBy` will be applied to the first query (`SELECT * FROM sliders_images ...`), so if you'll check generated sql:

```
echo $model->getImages()->createCommad()->rawSql;
```

then you will see something like this

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE id IN (4, 2, 3, 1)
```

and here will be correct order. But in resulting set you got order by id (1, 2, 3, 4).

So to get right order you should add desired `orderBy` to your `hasMany`:

```
public function getImages(){
  return $this->hasMany(Images::className(), ['id' => 'image_id'])
    ->viaTable('sliders_images', ['slider_id' => 'id'])
    ->orderBy(['images.display_order' => SORT_ASC]);
}
```

Related topic: [ActiveRecord where and order on via-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690401/activerecord-where-and-order-on-via-table)

Comment: Korshunow thanks for replay, your suggestion isn't the right way but open my mind to find the solution. The table images has no display_order attribute, this is a junction table attribute. For have the junction table attribute in the query I need a `joinWith()` statement. Follows the right answer.

Comment: Oh, missed that ) You right. Actually i always prefer to declare separated AR entities for every table and deal with `via` and `joinWith` instead of direct table references in relations and queries. This approach leads to more clean, flexible and sustainable code IMHO. So, definitely, you on the right way ))