# Yii2. How to sort results by attributes in junction table?

Tags: sorting, yii2, many-to-many

I have 3 tables: `sp_pages`, `sp_messages` and `sp_messages_pages` (for many-to-many relations).
The `sp_messages_pages` table have 5 columns:

- id
- page_id
- message_id
- enabled
- sorting_order

I want to get all messages for specific page sorting by `sp_messages_pages.sorting_order` using Yii2 framework.

I try this code in `pages` class:

```
public function getMessages() {
    return $this->hasMany(Messages::className(), ['id' => 'id_messages'])
    ->viaTable('sp_messages_pages', ['id_pages' => 'id'], function ($query) {
        $query->andWhere(['enabled' => 'Yes'])
                ->orderBy(['sp_messages_pages.sorting' => SORT_ASC]);
    });
}
```

I use this code in my controller:

```
$this->findModel(['slug' => $slug])->getMessages();
```

This give me all messages sorted by `sp_message.id`. The generated SQL is

> SELECT * FROM `sp_messages` WHERE `id` IN ('2', '3', '1', '4', '5')

`IN` condition is sorted as I want, but how to sort `sp_messages`?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355984/yii2-order-items-of-many-to-many-relation/38367858 the same topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First way -- joining relation table to already selected `messages`**

```
$this->hasMany(Messages::className(), ['id' => 'id_messages']) 
    ->viaTable('sp_messages_pages', ['id_pages' => 'id'], 
        function ($query) { 
            $query->andWhere(['enabled' => 'Yes']); 
        }
    )
    ->leftJoin('sp_messages_pages MP', 'MP.id_messages = sp_messages.id')
    ->orderBy(['MP.sorting' => SORT_ASC]);
```

almost the the same question here: [Yii2 order items of many-to-many relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355984/yii2-order-items-of-many-to-many-relation/38367858)

**Other way -- using findBySql**

```
$sql = "
    SELECT m.* FROM sp_messages AS m
    JOIN WITH sp_messages_pages AS mp ON mp.id_messages = m.id
    JOIN WITH sp_pages AS p ON p.id = mp.id_pages
    WHERE mp.enabled = 'Yes' AND p.id = :page_id
    ORDER BY mp.sorting ASC
";

return Messages::findBySql($sql, [':page_id' => $this->id]);
```

but this is will be not a relation in Yii therms, just an method which returns `ActiveQuery` for further work. You can use such method as `$page->getMessages()->all()` for example.

Comment: I am sorry, relation table name is `sp_messages_pages`. Unfortunately you code is not working for me, bot I began to study via + join..

Comment: @Psyhos also you can try do it using `findBySql` method: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#findBySql()-detail

Comment: @Psyhos the answer updated. Added second option with `findBySql` usage and fixed error in first example (i forgot to include `enabled` field in where). Check it out

Comment: Generic SQL variant is working perfect! (only add `->all()` after  `findBySql` command). The first variant did not give any result, but idea is clear. Many thanks, Maxim!

Comment: @Psyhos you are welcome. Glad to help you. But I would like also to fix the mistake in the first example, so that the response remains correct. Maybe this will help someone else. Do you see what is wrong here?

Comment: Great! Let's fix the mistake! The code in you answer return error: `Getting unknown property: app\modules\staticpages\models\Pages::sp_pages.id`. Then I change `sp_pages.id` to `id` in `viaTable` and get error: `Undefined index: sp_messages_pages.id_messages`. I think that in `$this->hasMany(Messages::className(), ..` we don't need to use table names. So I try to use `$this->hasMany(Messages::className(), ['id' => 'id_messages'])->viaTable('sp_messages_pages', ['id_pages' => 'id'], ..`.

Comment: Generated SQL is: SELECT `sp_messages`.* FROM `sp_messages` LEFT JOIN `sp_messages_pages` `MP` ON (`MP`.`id_pages`='sp_pages.id') AND (`MP`.`id_messages`='sp_messages.id') WHERE `sp_messages`.`id` IN ('1', '2', '5') ORDER BY `MP`.`sorting`

Comment: This give right result without sorting. I think that LEFT JOIN  is wrong - 'sp_pages.id' and 'sp_messages.id' in single quotes like string values..

Comment: @Psyhos got it. Using column name with table name as value in where condition is not working, because yii will escape it. Fixed. Try now

Comment: Yes, you are right. Working variant is:  return $this->hasMany(Messages::className(), ['id' => 'id_messages'])
    ->viaTable('sp_messages_pages', ['id_pages' => 'id'], function ($query) {
        $query->andWhere(['enabled' => 'Yes']);
    })
    ->leftJoin('sp_messages_pages MP', ' MP.id_messages = sp_messages.id')
    ->orderBy(['MP.sorting' => SORT_ASC]);  Thank you! Greetings from Estonia :)